# Matlab simulation: Query regarding generating random numbers

Tags: matlab, simulation, octave

I am doing some simulations studies and for initial stuides I am trying to simulate 100 gas particles and then grouping of these gas particles in 5 groups randomly for 10 or 100 times (non zero values in any groups). after that i have to find the group with highest particle and the number.

for example

```
 100 gas particles

  1  2  3  4  5(groups)  Total particle  group/Highest number
 20|20|20|20|20           100             1-2-3-4-5/20
 70|16|04|01|09           100             1/70
 18|28|29|10|15           100             3/29
 .
 .
 etc
```

i have used this to generate 5 random numbers for a single time

```
for i=1:1
randi([1,100],1,5)
end    
ans =

    50    41     9    60    88
```

but how will i find the highest number and group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the max function :

```
a = [50    41     9    60    88];
[C,I] = max(a)
```

C should be equal to 88 and I to 4.

For the special case of equality (first line in your code), you have to read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to see the result of max. I think the index returned will be the first max.

Comment: try with brackets  (I cannot test my code, I don't have Matlab on my work machine)

Comment: I have inserted the square brackets before C,I. it worked thanks